# Query paramater is undefined in my API in Next.js app router

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to create an API making a delete request that will remove an album from a users document within the database (MongoDB atlas).

I keep getting an error saying that the `albumName` property is undefined, and I can not figure out why.

For reference, the user will select which album they'd like to delete on the page, and it will delete that album. In the database, albums is an array of album objects, album has 2 properties, albumName and outfits (another array).

Delete API:

```
import { connect } from "@/dbConfig/dbConfig";
import User from "@/models/userModel";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

connect();

export async function DELETE(request) {
  const token = request.cookies.get("token")?.value || '';
  const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token);
  const email = decodedToken ? decodedToken.email : '';
  
  const albumName = request.query.albumName; // Extract albumName from query params

  try {
    const userEmail = email.toLowerCase();

    if (!userEmail || !albumName) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: "Email or albumName not provided" }, { status: 400 });
    }

    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { email: userEmail },
      { $pull: { albums: { albumName: albumName } } },
      { new: true }
    );

    if (!user) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: "User not found" }, { status: 404 });
    }

    if (!user.albums.find(album => album.albumName === albumName)) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: "Album not found in user's albums" }, { status: 404 });
    }

    return NextResponse.json({ success: true, message: "Album deleted successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

Albums page.js:

```
'use client';

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faTrashCan } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import Link from 'next/link';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function AlbumsPage() {
  const [albumName, setAlbumName] = useState('');
  const [albums, setAlbums] = useState([]);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [deleteAlbumName, setDeleteAlbum] = useState(''); 
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const fetchAlbums = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/api/users/getUserAlbums');
      setAlbums(response.data.albums);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAlbums();
  }, []);

  const handleCreateAlbum = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
    setErrorMessage('');
  };

  const handleModalInputChange = (e) => {
    setAlbumName(e.target.value);
    setErrorMessage('');
  };

  const handleModalClose = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
    setAlbumName('');
  };

  const handleModalSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/api/users/createAlbums', { albumName });
      console.log(albumName);

      setAlbums(prevAlbums => [...prevAlbums, { albumName }]);
      setShowModal(false);
      setAlbumName('');
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        if (error.response.status === 400) {
          setErrorMessage('Album already exists');
        } else {
          setErrorMessage('Failed to create album');
        }
      } else {
        setErrorMessage('Network error. Please try again.');
      }
    }
  };

  const handleDeleteAlbum = async (albumName) => {
    setDeleteAlbum(albumName); 
    setShowModal(true); 
  };

  const confirmDeleteAlbum = async () => {
    if (deleteAlbumName) { 
      console.log('Deleting album:', deleteAlbumName); // Log the album name
      try {
        const response = await axios.delete(`api/users/deleteAlbums?albumName=${deleteAlbumName}`);
        setShowModal(false);
        setDeleteAlbum('');
        fetchAlbums(); 
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('Failed to delete album');
      }
    }
  };
  
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
      if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        event.preventDefault();
        handleModalSubmit();
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
    };
  }, [albumName]);

  return (
    <main>
      {showModal && (
        <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-50 z-50"></div>
      )}
  
      {showModal && (
        <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center z-50">
          <div className="bg-white p-10 rounded-md shadow-lg">
            {deleteAlbumName ? ( 
              <>
                <h2 className="text-lg font-semibold mb-2">Are you sure you want to delete this album?</h2>
                <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
                  <button className="bg-black text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-md mr-2 font-semibold" onClick={confirmDeleteAlbum}>Yes</button>
                  <button className="bg-gray-300 text-gray-800 px-4 py-2 rounded-md font-semibold" onClick={handleModalClose}>No</button>
                </div>
              </>
            ) : (
              <>
                <h2 className="text-lg font-semibold mb-2">Enter Album Name</h2>
                {errorMessage && <p className='text-sm text-red-500 mb-2'>{errorMessage}</p>}
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="border border-gray-300 rounded-md p-2 mb-2 outline-none"
                  value={albumName}
                  onChange={handleModalInputChange}
                  placeholder='Album Name'
                />
                <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
                  <button className="bg-black text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-md mr-2 font-semibold" onClick={handleModalSubmit}>Create</button>
                  <button className="bg-gray-300 text-gray-800 px-4 py-2 rounded-md font-semibold" onClick={handleModalClose}>Cancel</button>
                </div>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
  
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center bg-gray-300 shadow-lg p-4">
        <h1 className="font-bold text-3xl mb-4">Albums</h1>
        <button className="bg-black text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-xl mb-4 font-semibold" onClick={handleCreateAlbum}>
          Create Album
        </button>
      </div>
  
      <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 m-5">
        {albums.map((album, index) => (
          album && album.albumName && ( 
            <div key={index} className="bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md p-4 relative text-center">
              <Link href={`/albums/${album.albumName}`} className="text-lg font-semibold mb-2 hover:opacity-70">{album.albumName}</Link>
              <button
                className="absolute bottom-0 right-0 bg-transparent text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-md font-semibold"
                onClick={() => handleDeleteAlbum(album.albumName)}
                title='Delete Album'
              >
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} className='text-red-500' />
              </button>
            </div>
          )
        ))}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They way you are trying to get the query parameter is not correct within the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router. As you can read on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#url-query-parameters), it should be this way:

```js
export function DELETE(request) {
  // ...

  const searchParams = request.nextUrl.searchParams
  const albumName = searchParams.get('albumName')

  //...
}
```

Also, you would want to use an absolute URL on the client in `confirmDeleteAlbum` and await `fetchAlbums` to sync the changes better:

```js
const confirmDeleteAlbum = async () => {
  if (deleteAlbumName) {
    console.log("Deleting album:", deleteAlbumName); // Log the album name
    try {
      const response = await axios.delete(`/api/users/deleteAlbums?albumName=${deleteAlbumName}`);
      setShowModal(false);
      setDeleteAlbum("");
      await fetchAlbums();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      console.log("Failed to delete album");
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: This almost worked! Whats happening now is it is correctly deleting from the database, but its still throwing a 404 error and saying 'Failed to delete album' even though its correctly deleting from the database.

Comment: Glad I could help! This is weired. What's is in your console.log(error) before the console.log('Failed to delete album' )?

Comment: it says:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
AxiosError
code
: 
"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"

Comment: I think I see the problem. Checkout my latest edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, its still giving the same error. I cant even see how its giving that error considering it is deleting from the db

Comment: In the same `confirmDeleteAlbum`, add an `await` in front of fetchAlbums. It may not be the source of the problem, but you would want the function to terminate after the fech are done.

Comment: after looking deeper into the axios error, i see this:
data: error: "Album not found in user's albums"
this error comes from the api, i think this is where the issue is stemming from

Comment: I do'nt see why you have this `if (!user.albums.find(album => album.albumName === albumName))`. The album is removed, so `!user.albums.find(album => album.albumName === albumName)` will enter the `if` by defenition, right?

Comment: wow, that was it. Thanks so much for all the help man, crazy how it was just that if statement giving me all these issues lol

Comment: Yeah, it happens. It's my pleasure @gj_dev ! Feel free to let others know your problem is solved by accepting the answer (check button next). Cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

The delete request is expecting albumName as a query parameter. However, in the API, you're trying to access albumName from the query object, So  you are getting error as "albumName property is undefined"

Modify below line in Delete API:

```
  const albumName = request.params.albumName; // Access albumName from params
```

in Page.js

```
const response = await axios.delete(`api/users/deleteAlbums`, {
  params: {
    albumName: deleteAlbumName
  }
});
```